# To check if the user has already ran the program within the given time

Tags: c#

I created a program which is working absolutely fine. However, I'm stuck in one particular phase. Here it goes - when the user run the program and clicks on a button in the windows form for the first time; the program will perform the dsired task in my case it will scan  a particualr directory for a file and displays the results accordingly. However, if the user runs the program and clicks on a button a with in the next 4 hours from the first run; the program should ask the user to try after 4 hours and it should not perform the desired task which have done when the user ran the program for the first time. only after 4 hours user should be able to search on the directory.

please help me...

Comment: When your user presses the button store the time in some non-volatile storage - registry, file on disk, wherever. Next time the button is pressed, check the time from the time before.

Comment: Thank you...let me try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously your program has to remember the last time of execution. You have several options where to store this information. The obvious choices are a file in the local file system and the Windows registry, but you could also upload this timestamp data to a database or web service. Below is a code snippet for storing the current date and time into a local file.

Do this when the user clicks the button and is allowed to invoke your action:

```
File.WriteAllText("filename.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

When the user clicks again check the time of last successful execution this way:

```
string timestamp = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
DateTime lastRun = DateTime.Parse(timestamp);
if (DateTime.Now > lastRun.AddHours(4))
{
    // user is allowed to invoke functionality again
}
```

NB: This approach is not very secure because the user could look for the file and delete it. Hence, you should think about your trust model and answer the question how cooperative/destructive the user is.